# Extract a single directory from rpm

Tags: linux, bash, rpm

I'm able to extract individual file **rpm** rpm by:

```
rpm2cpio rpm_name | cpio -ivd ./a/b/c/README
```

I need to extract the whole /a/b/c/ directory (using ./a/b/c/ in above command doesn't works)?

1. How it can be done?
2. Can I indicate where to create directory "c/" instead of ./a/b/c?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. use a wildcard, but be careful to protect it from the shell:

   `rpm2cpio rpm_name | cpio -ivd './a/b/c/*'`
2. Not directly, but `cpio` does have a `-r/--rename` switch. There are unfortunately two problems with that: it asks about each file and it takes input from `/dev/tty` directly. Which means it's not easy to automate it. You could use the `expect` program if you really wanted to do it. **Warning**: not for the faint of heart ;) Note that it doesn't handle files with quotes (or possibly spaces) properly. It expects the name of the rpm file, a pattern for the files to extract and a `sed` command to transform each file. Usage example:

   `cpio.sh rpm_name './a/b/c/*' 's#^./a/b/#foo/#'`

Theoretically the script could be piped into `expect` but that's left as an excercise for the reader.

```
#! /bin/bash

SCRIPT=/tmp/$$.expect
RPM="$1"
FILES="$2"
TRANSFORM="$3"

echo "spawn sh -c \"rpm2cpio \\\"$RPM\\\" | cpio -ird '$FILES'\"" > "$SCRIPT"
rpm2cpio "$RPM" | cpio -it "$FILES" 2>/dev/null | sed "$TRANSFORM" | while read line
do
    echo "send \"$line\\r\"" >> "$SCRIPT"
done
echo "wait" >> "$SCRIPT"
expect "$SCRIPT"
rm -f "$SCRIPT"
```

Comment: Your 1st solution is what I was looking for. Thanks